# RegEx to Parse URL from text (text Contains HTML tags)

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to parse the URLs from the Given Text,

Input Text:-

```
 <h3 class="r"> <a
 href="/url?q=http://rakesh.agrawal-family.com/papers/vldbj03watermark.pdf&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=m2laUfD2AdDorQf0rYHoDw&amp;ved=0CBoQFjAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNFJOQCS471sWjxy5CkNbzDxzcD66A">
 <h3 class="r"> <a
 href="/url?q=http://www.cse.ust.hk/vldb2002/VLDB2002-proceedings/papers/S05P03.pdf&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=m2laUfD2AdDorQf0rYHoDw&amp;ved=0CCIQFjAD&amp;usg=AFQjCNHbfCk_51dKLupvs3KVVEDboK54xg">
 <h3 class="r"> <a
 href="/url?q=http://cvml.unige.ch/publications/postscript/99/VoloshynovskiyPereiraPun_eww99.pdf&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=m2laUfD2AdDorQf0rYHoDw&amp;ved=0CCYQFjAE&amp;usg=AFQjCNGt54TSNY93PXgd4u4L3-E6C6P2jw">
```

Expected Output:

http://rakesh.agrawal-family.com/papers/vldbj03watermark.pdf

http://www.cse.ust.hk/vldb2002/VLDB2002-proceedings/papers/S05P03.pdf

http://cvml.unige.ch/publications/postscript/99/VoloshynovskiyPereiraPun_eww99.pdf

Sample Code:-

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"<h3 class=""r""> <a href=""/url\?q=(.*?)&amp;", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);         
while (match.Success)            
{                
// Finally, we get the Group value and display it.                
string key = match.Groups[1].Value;                
Console.WriteLine(key);                
match = match.NextMatch();
```

Comment: Maybe you can use http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com to firstly retrieve all href attributes, than use classic string manipulation to extract the relevant part?

Comment: Obligatory http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/113586

Answer (score 0):

Note that mixing HTML and regexes is not advised.

But if you are looking for a quick hack, you can use this regex:

```
url\?q=\*\*[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)\*\*
```

Here check this link: http://rubular.com/r/v0jqtAXMF9

Answer (score 0):

RegExs build DFAs and hence are pretty expensive,
if you need to extract data from a known pattern, you could use this,

```
url=line[i].substring(line[i].indexOf("q=")+1, line[i].indexOf(">\""));
```

Basically using a linear search of indexes rather than complex DFAs

Comment: I cant use Index of... Am having Complete Html page.... also 20 Links,. So I need to use Regex..